# react-native-firebase firestore permission denied

Tags: firebase, react-native, permission-denied, google-cloud-firestore

What I'm trying to do here is to actually just read data from my firestore. I followed all the installation from RNF's docs, but when I try to get data from my documents or just reference into firestore collection, an error shows up:

[image: react native firebase error]

I tried changing the rules (as I thought it was the rules involved) but no luck.
Here is my database structure:

[image: database structure]

And below are my codes :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, Text, FlatList, Image, StyleSheet, Button, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import MainApp from './src/screen/test';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.itemsRef = this.getRef('questions');
    this.state = {
      items:[],
      loading:true,
    };

  }

  setModalVisible(visible){
    this.setState(modalVisible:visible);
  }
  getRef(location){
    return firebase.firestore().collection('chat');
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    this.getItems(this.itemsRef);
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    //this.getItems(this.itemsRef);
  }
  getItems(itemsRef){
    firebase.firestore().collection('Users').get().then((snap)=>{
      let items =[];
      alert(snap);
      snap.forEach((childSnap)=>{
        items.push({
        title:childSnap.val().question,
        _key:childSnap.key
        });
        alert(childSnap.key)
      })
      this.setState({
        items,
        loading:false
      })
    })
  }
  pressRow(item){
    alert(item);
  }
  renderRow(item){
    return(
      <TouchableHighLight onPress={()=>{
        this.pressRow(item)
      }}>
      <View>
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </View>
      </TouchableHighLight>
    )
  }
  addItem(){

  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
    return null; // or render a loading icon
    }
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.items}
      />
      <Button
          title={'Add TODO'}
          onPress={() => console.log()}
      />
  </View>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you post your rules (either as a picture or as text)?

Answer (score 0):

The default setting for firestore is to disable access.

So if you don't have your access rules set up, you can't fetch data.

Change them to this - but ONLY for testing:

`service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Match all documents, recursively, with a wildcard and the "=**" recursive modifier
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}`

Then after it works - read more about [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview).

Comment: can you try to create a stackblitz for debugging?