# Why will the firestore document id print to the console but not the document data in my web app?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

[image]I'm using .net, Javascript and Visual Studio 2017. When I run the code below from within script tags it prints out:

> V5hzmxxxxxxxGr6VyxxxxxtUA3  =>  <unavailable>

Here's the code:

```
var db = firebase.firestore();

db.collection("users").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});
```

Where `doc.id` is the fireauth ID. I've checked the database and there is definitely a document there. So I'm wondering why it says unavailable.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you log `doc.metadata` as well?

Comment: hi @raina77ow. V5hxxxxxxxxxxGGr6Vy4UtUA3  =>  <unavailable>  =>  <unavailable>  - the 2nd unavailable is doc.metadata - i checked my database rules and i allow both read and write. in cloud functions i haven't setup my billing account because to date i haven't been using any 3rd party libraries - not sure if this related.

Comment: I tested using microsoft edge instead of firefox and maybe it says permission denied (see above).

Comment: Possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46949592/5882767

Comment: Yeah i figured it out. So I changed the api  key and tested again with microsoft edge and the documents printed to the console. But even though they printed with edge firefox was still say V5xxxxx => unavailable. So went back to edge and printed doc.data()["firstname"] which printed out and even though firefox says unavilable doc.data()["firstname"] pritned to the console in firefox.